# Java : how to know when a XML Document has been modified

Tags: java, xml, listener, document, domdocument

Is there some clean method to know when some content of a DOM Document has been modified, without having to recurse into its nodes and hashing tons of data ?

I would avoid to generate the full XML String (see @AdriaanKoster' response)

Using a listener or whatever "clever", as @mthmulders pointed it out, seems to be the right way.

I found an interesting SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487492/javadom-registering-and-using-modification-listeners-tutorials), maybe is it THE answer ?

Any tip ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether your `Document` also is an instance of [`EventTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/EventTarget.html). If so, you can use the `addEventListener` method to handle any events. For example, if the event being handled is a [`MutationEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/MutationEvent.html), you might get information about the modification to the document.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unable to find out relevant examples. Do you have some ?

Comment: I found that :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487492/javadom-registering-and-using-modification-listeners-tutorials But I wonder if it will have effect on the *full* tree.

Comment: Take a look at the [Document Object Model Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html), specifically the [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents).

Comment: Ok, DOMSubtreeModified seems to be what I'm looking for : a generic way to handle a non-peculiar change in the document content. I'll validate (or not) the answer whan I'll be done.

Answer (score 1):

I did this once by serializing the Document to String and taking its hashcode. Not an extremely expensive operation I think. It goes something like this:

```
private int calculateHashCode(org.w3c.dom.Document document) {
    try { 
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty("indent","no");
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);        
        return stringWriter.toString().hashCode();
    }
    catch(TransformerException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I am returning -1 in case of an exception because I don't want to burden the calling code with exception handling whilst determining the hashCode. It means that changes in documents which cannot be transformed successfully will not be detected correctly.

Comment: Oops I did not write "without generating the full text". I fixed it. Thanks for your answer, since it fits the problem. +1

Comment: Nice idea. Taking the `hashCode` isn't particularly expensive, I agree. But how about writing the DOM tree to a `String`? Either case, this solution is pulling for changes (you have to do this when you suspect a change) while the event listening is pushing events (you always get notified of changes, regardless of whether you check for them or not). It might be simpler to implement, though.

Comment: I guess it depends on the use case. If your code has the Document in memory all the time you can listen for change events. However if you are pulling it from a remote source once in a while and want to check if it has changed you cannot do that and will have to use some sort of hashing approach.